# Migrate PrimeFaces: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jboss6.x

This problem appears when I migrate PrimeFaces 3.3 to 3.4.

I'm using the JQuery.Numberic Version 1.3 plugin, JSF 2.2.14 and Jboss EAP 6.4.

InputText i put feature numeric on ready jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...    
$(".numeric").numeric({ decimal : false , negative : false });
...
}
```

Change value in InputText component in Primefaces version 3.4 in console browser shows:

```
jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:373 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
    at Object.setSelection (jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:373)
    at HTMLInputElement.$.fn.numeric.keyup (jquery.numeric.js:262)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.b4 (jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:14)
(anonymous) @ jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:373
$.fn.numeric.keyup @ jquery.numeric.js:262
dispatch @ jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:14
b4 @ jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces:14
```

The error start in this line on plug-in file jquery.numeric.js:

```
$.fn.setSelection(this, [carat, selectionEnd]);
```

**Using PrimeFaces 3.3.1 this error doesn't occur**

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and [mcve] and improve your question

Comment: the changes are better?

Comment: Not really, please read the links I posted carefully. Also read